# What does this symbol means, what operator is it?

Tags: neural-network, gan, generative-models

[image: loss fuction of Generative Adversarial Networks]

I am confused about the $E_{x\sim P_{data}(x)}$, what does $E$ means here. I cannot find an appropriate answer on the internet, and hence I am trying data science stack exchange. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{E}$ means [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value).

The subscript is there to clarify which random variable is the expected value taken.